# The chess example 10-1-12 /LaTeX Graphics Companion/

Tags: pdftex, chess, chessboard, mwe

I'm trying to compile the example10-1-12  from LaTeX Graphics Companion
but it gives an error:

Command Line:   bibtex.exe "chess2"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: chess2.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file chess2.aux

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/psnfss\t1ptm.fd)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/enpassant\lsfmagnetic.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LSF/magnetic/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using`LSF/magnetic/m/n' instead on input line 26.

! mainline: white, not black, to move (b5).
 ...ine: white, not black, to move (b5)}

l.31            7. e4}
                      .
?

! Emergency stop.
 ...ine: white, not black, to move (b5)}

l.31            7. e4}
                      .

---

PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

Errors: 2   Warnings: 1   Bad Boxes: 0

---

(Nota: the `ttctexa` class file can be found [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/examples/lgc2/ttctexa.cls), it is not installed by default in TeXlive nor MikTeX)

```
%%
%%  The LaTeX Graphics Companion, 2ed (first printing May 2007)
%%
%%  Example 10-1-12 on page 678.
%%
%%  Copyright (C) 2007 Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, Denis Roegel, Sebastian Rahtz, Herbert Vo\ss
%%
%%  It may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions
%%  of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%%  of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%%
%%  See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt for details.
%%

\documentclass{ttctexa}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{6}
\setlength\textwidth{231.83385pt}
\StartShownPreambleCommands
\usepackage{skak}
\smallboard
\setchessfontfamily{magnetic}
\StopShownPreambleCommands
\begin{document}
\newgame
\mainline{1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 c5 3. d5}
A possible continuation is the Benko
Gambit.
\variation{3... b5 4. cxb5 a6
           5. bxa6 Bxa6 6. Nc3 d6
           7. e4}.
Here the game follows the Classical
Benoni opening
\mainline{3... e6 4. Nc3 exd5
          5.cxd5 d6 6. e4 g6}
leading after some additional moves
\ldots\hidemoves{7. Nf3 Bg7 8. Be2 O-O}
to \mainline{9. O-O a6 10.a4 Bg4}.
\begin{center} \showboard \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The newest `skak` version has changed the behaviour of `variation`. It no longer types only moves, it also tries to parse the game and that makes it more pickier regarding the moves: A variation has to be a variation. So you should move the `e6` mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{6}
\setlength\textwidth{231.83385pt}
%\StartShownPreambleCommands
\usepackage{skak}
\smallboard
\setchessfontfamily{magnetic}
%\StopShownPreambleCommands
\begin{document}
\newgame
\mainline{1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 c5 3. d5 e6}
A possible continuation is the Benko
Gambit.
\variation{3... b5 4. cxb5 a6
           5. bxa6 Bxa6 6. Nc3 d6
           7. e4}.
Here the game follows the Classical
Benoni opening
\mainline{4. Nc3 exd5
          5.cxd5 d6 6. e4 g6}
leading after some additional moves
\ldots\hidemoves{7. Nf3 Bg7 8. Be2 O-O}
to \mainline{9. O-O a6 10.a4 Bg4}.

\begin{center} \showboard \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Instead of skak you could use xskak where variation doesn't parse:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{6}
\setlength\textwidth{231.83385pt}
%\StartShownPreambleCommands
\usepackage{xskak}
\xskakset{style=styleB}
\setchessboard{smallboard}

%\setchessfontfamily{magnetic}
%\StopShownPreambleCommands
\begin{document}
\newgame
\mainline{1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 c5 3. d5}
A possible continuation is the Benko
Gambit.
\variation[invar]{3... b5 4. cxb5 a6
           5. bxa6 Bxa6 6. Nc3 d6
           7. e4}.
Here the game follows the Classical
Benoni opening
\mainline[outvar]{3...  e6 4. Nc3 exd5
          5.cxd5 d6 6. e4 g6}
leading after some additional moves
\ldots\hidemoves{7. Nf3 Bg7 8. Be2 O-O}
to \mainline{9. O-O a6 10.a4 Bg4}.

\begin{center} \chessboard \end{center}
\end{document}
```